# twitter retweet user id api python

Tags: python, api, twitter, social-networking

using the twitter api with python, I need to know how to get all the user ids of all the people that retweeted a tweet.

I went here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/%3Aid/retweeted_by

but I do not know how to put that into python.

here is my code so far:

```
from twitter import *
t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(....))
twitter = t.statuses.user_timeline.snl()

twitter[0]['text']           # gets the tweet
twitter[0]['retweet_count']  # gets the number of retweets
```

what is my next line to get the IDs of all the users who retweeted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [retweets_of_me](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets_of_me) for twitter API 1.1, `retweeted_by` is deprecated and doesn't work.

Here's an example:

```
from twitter import *

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(...))

tweets = t.statuses.user_timeline.snl()

for tweet in tweets:
    retweets = t.statuses.retweets_of_me(since_id=str(tweet['id']), max_id=str(tweet['id']))
    print retweets
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Check this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1. AFAIK, python twitter client supports them all.